# How do I select tables from a different schema using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework provider?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I've seen this question in various places on the internet; but none of the answers I've seen are newer than 2011 (and none of those seem to work).

At any rate, when I access the server, it attempts to show me tables associated with my user' schema; however, I need to generate entities for another schema for which I have read access.

DevArt suggests that specific kind of table grant needs to be used; but as I'm not an Oracle dev, I don't know if this is specific to their provider or universal to the Oracle server.  Either way, it appears not to have worked.

The trick from 2011 of editing the server connection filters has no effect on the EDM Wizard (or else it needs a special form of save not obvious in the UI); and so far, I've found no Connection String entry for specifying schema (which would be too convenient.)

For the record, I'm working with EF6; and I haven't worked with Oracle in almost a decade.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your DBA to do the following:

1) Make sure the DBA grants the account, which you are using in connection string, SELECT access to the oracle table.

```
grant select on myschema.mytable to group_or_username;
```

2) Make sure the DBA creates a synonym in the other schema you are trying to access.

```
create or replace synonym anotherschema.mytable for myschema.mytable;
```

3) Make sure to include the schema name before your table name in ORM tool.

HTH

Comment: ha, what a pain to use MS tech with non MS systems.  I did the first part, but I never would have assumed I'd have to do the second part.  When my DBAs get more time, I'll give this a shot.  I'm betting you're right, so, I'm marking you right now.  Thanks